# JKMount is not picking up .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I'm trying to pass any request for my webapp to the tomcat container using mod_jk, everything looks good when requesting .jsp and static files, but i'm using a .htaccess file to make friendly urls, which is not working for some reason with the current configuration, this is the vhost.conf I have:

```
DirectoryIndex index.jsp index.htm index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_jk.c>
    JkMount / ajp13
    JkMount /* ajp13
</IfModule>

RewriteLog /etc/httpd/logs/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3

DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat6/psa-webapps/localkicks.com
<Directory /usr/share/tomcat6/psa-webapps/localkicks.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

with a basic rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?editorial_search$ news_search_result.jsp [L]
```

Why would this be happening?

Comment: ¿How is the incoming URL for the rewrite rule in your question?

Comment: something like http://www.localkicks.com/editorial_search

Answer (score 0):

You can use JkUnMount. Even like this you can still have problems with JSESSIONID. Try enabling cookies.

**JkUnMount** / ajp13
    JkMount /* ajp13